# How do I write this recursive function to find the max depth of my object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that will loop through my object and return the level depth of the object.

For example, if I ran the function on this object:

```
var test = {
  name: 'item 1',
  children: [{
    name: 'level 1 item',
    children: [{
      name: 'level 2 item'
    },
    {
      name: 'second level 2 item',
      children: [{
        name: 'level 3 item'
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

var depth = myFunction(test); // Would return 2 (0 index based) as the collection goes 3 levels deep
```

I've been trying to write a recursive function that determines the maximum depth but so far I can't get it right. This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/6cc6kdaw/2/

It seems the value returned is a count of every node hit, not unique levels. I understand where I'm going wrong (in the sense that I'm not filtering this out) but I'm at the point where I've been staring at the code for so long that nothing's making sense any more!

Anyone able to point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem/code in the question itself and not only a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit to work as you want it to:

```
function getDepth(node, depth = 0) {
    if (!!node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
        var childDepths = [];
        depth++;

        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            childDepths.push(getDepth(node.children[i]));
        }
        return depth + Math.max(...childDepths);
    }

    return depth;
}

var depth = getDepth(root);

console.log('currentMaxDepth', depth);
console.log('root', root);
```

The trick is to measure depths of siblings on the same level and than pick the deepest of them. Here's also a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xk7zn00/

Answer (score 10):

**beauty**

The depth function is one of those functions that's expressed so beautifully with recursion – this answer is similar to Nina's but illustrates a different line of reasoning.

```
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  children.length === 0
    ? 0                                      // base
    : 1 + Math.max (...children.map (depth)) // inductive
```

First we destructure the incoming node, assigning `children = []` when the property isn't set. This allows us to attack the problem using the traditional base and inductive cases for arrays:

- **base case**: the array is empty
- **inductive case**: the array is *not* empty, therefore we have *at least one* element to handle

Nina's answer very cleverly avoids any `if` or ternary `?:` altogether! She does this by sneaking the base case in as the first argument to `Math.max`! She's so smart <3

Here's a functioning example

```js
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  children.length === 0
    ? 0
    : 1 + Math.max (...children.map (depth))

const test = 
  { name: 'level 0 item'
  , children: 
      [ { name: 'level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children:
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item' } ]
              }
            ]
        }
      , { name: 'second level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children: 
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item'
                    , children:
                        [ { name: 'level 4 item' } ]
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }

console.log (depth (test))
// 4
```

---

**the beast**

We used some high-level functions and language utilities above. If we are new to this concept, we cannot achieve higher-level thinking before first learning to think at the lower levels

- `Math.max` accepts any number of arguments. How does this work exactly?
- We use rest argument syntax `...children` to convert an array of values as individual arguments in a function call. How does this conversion work exactly?
- We use `map` from the `Array.prototype` to transform our array of children nodes into an array of node depths. How does this work? Do we really need to make a *new* array?

To foster an appreciation for these built-in functions and features, we'll look at how to achieve such results on our own. We'll revisit `depth` but this time we'll replace all of that magic with our own hard work

```
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  children.length === 0
    ? 0                        // base
    : 1 + magicWand (children) // inductive
```

Now we just need a magic wand... first, we start with some basic crafting materials

```
const isEmpty = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0

const first = (xs = []) =>
  xs [0]

const rest = (xs = []) =>
  xs.slice (1)
```

I want to keep thinking about the *base* and *inductive* cases, and these primitive functions compliment that line of reasoning.

Let's first get an intuition for how `magicWand` will (must) work

```
// magicWand takes a list of nodes and must return a number
1 + magicWand (children)
```

So let's look at our two cases

- **base case**: the input list `isEmpty`, so return 0 – there are no children, so there is no depth to add
- **inductive case**: there list has *at least one* child – calculate the depth of the `first` item, wave the magic wand on the `rest`, and take the `max` of those two values

Our magic wand is complete

```
const magicWand = (list = []) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    // base
    ? 0
    // inductive
    : max ( depth (first (list))
          , magicWand (rest (list))
          )
```

All that's left is to define `max`

```
const max = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x > y
    ? x
    : y
```

Just to make sure everything is still working at this point...

```js
const max = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x > y
    ? x
    : y

const isEmpty = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0

const first = (xs = []) =>
  xs [0]

const rest = (xs = []) =>
  xs.slice (1)

const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  children.length === 0
    ? 0                        // base
    : 1 + magicWand (children) // inductive
    
const magicWand = (list = []) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    // base
    ? 0
    // inductive
    : max ( depth (first (list))
          , magicWand (rest (list))
          )

const test = 
  { name: 'level 0 item'
  , children: 
      [ { name: 'level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children:
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item' } ]
              }
            ]
        }
      , { name: 'second level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children: 
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item'
                    , children:
                        [ { name: 'level 4 item' } ]
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }

console.log (depth (test)) // 4
```

So to achieve higher-level thinking, you must first visualize what will happen when your program is run

```
const someList =
  [ x, y, z ]

magicWand (someList)
// ???
```

It doesn't matter what `x`, `y` and `z` are. You just have to imagine the function call stack that `magicWand` will build with each of the independent pieces. We can see how this would expand as more items are added to the input list...

```
max ( depth (x)
    , max ( depth (y)
          , max ( depth (z)
                , 0
                )
          )
    )
```

When we see the computation that our functions build, we start to see similarities in their structure. When a pattern emerges, we can capture its essence in a reusable function

In the computation above, `max` and `magicWand` are hard-coded into our program. If I wanted to compute a different value with the tree, I'd need an entirely different magic wand.

This function is called a *fold* because it folds a user-supplied function `f` between each element in a traversable data structure. You'll see our signature base and inductive cases

```
const fold = (f, base, list) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    ? base
    : f ( fold ( f
               , base
               , rest (list)
               )
        , first (list)
        )
```

Now we can rewrite `magicWand` using our generic `fold`

```
const magicWand = (list = []) =>
  fold ( (acc, x) => max (acc, depth (x))
       , 0
       , list
       )
```

The `magicWand` abstraction is no longer necessary. `fold` can be used directly in our original function.

```
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  children.length === 0
    ? 0
    : 1 + fold ( (acc, x) => max (acc, depth (x))
               , 0
               , children
               )
```

Of course it's much harder to read the original. Syntax sugars afford you all sorts of shortcuts in your code. The downside is beginners often feel there must always be some sort of sugary sweet [*"shorthand"*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+shorthand) solution to whatever their problem is – then they're stuck [when it's just not there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838385/633183).

Functioning code example

```js
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  isEmpty (children)
    ? 0
    : 1 + fold ( (acc, x) => max (acc, depth (x))
               , 0
               , children
               )

const fold = (f, base, list) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    ? base
    : f ( fold ( f
               , base
               , rest (list)
               )
        , first (list)
        )
        
const max = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x > y
    ? x
    : y

const isEmpty = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0
  
const first = (xs = []) =>
  xs [0]
  
const rest = (xs = []) =>
  xs.slice (1)

const test = 
  { name: 'level 0 item'
  , children: 
      [ { name: 'level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children:
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item' } ]
              }
            ]
        }
      , { name: 'second level 1 item'
        , children:
            [ { name: 'level 2 item' }
            , { name: 'second level 2 item'
              , children: 
                  [ { name: 'level 3 item'
                    , children:
                        [ { name: 'level 4 item' } ]
                    }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }

console.log (depth (test))
// 4
```

**beast mode**

Lurking in the last implementation of `depth` we saw this lambda (anonymous function) expression.

```
(acc, x) => max (acc, depth (x))
```

We are about to bear witness to an incredible invention of our own making. This little lambda is so useful we'll actually give it a name, but before we can harness its true power, we must first make `max` and `depth` parameters – we've crafted a new magic wand

```
const magicWand2 = (f, g) =>
  (acc, x) => g (acc, f (x))

const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  isEmpty (children)
    ? 0
    : 1 + fold (magicWand2 (depth, max), 0, children)

// Tada!
```

At first glance you think this must be the most useless magic wand ever! You might suspect I'm one of those zombies that won't stop until everything is [point-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointfree). You inhale and suspend your reactions for a brief moment

```
const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs.concat (ys)

const map = (f, list) =>
  fold (magicWand2 (f, concat), [], list)

map (x => x * x, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
// => [ 16, 9, 4, 1 ]
```

Admittedly, we think that's pretty cool. But we won't be dazzled by a 2-trick pony. You'd be wise to prevent just any old function from landing in your program or library, but you'd be a fool to overlook this one.

```
const filter = (f, list) =>
  fold ( magicWand2 (x => f (x) ? [ x ] : [], concat)
       , []
       , list
       )

filter (x => x > 2, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
// [ 4, 3 ]
```

Ok, aside from the fact that `map` and `filter` are assembling the result in "reverse" order, this magic wand has some serious heat. We'll call it `mapReduce` because it gives us two parameters, each of them a function, and creates a new reducing function to plug into `fold`

```
const mapReduce => (m, r) =>
  (acc, x) => r (acc, m (x))
```

1. `m`, the *mapping* function – this gives you a chance to transform the incoming element before ...
2. `r`, the *reducing* function – this function combines the accumulator with the result of the mapped element

As for `fold` assembling the result in "reverse", it's not. This just happens to be a *right-fold*. Below, we can imagine `f` as some binary function (ie `+`) – see the computations in prefix notation `f (x y)`, and infix notation `x + y` should help highlight the key difference

```
foldR (f, base, [ x, y, z ])
// = f (f (f (base, z), y), x)
// = ((base + z) + y) + x

foldL (f, base, [ x, y, z ])
// = f (f (f (base, x), y), z)
// = (((base + x) + y) + z
```

So let's define our left-fold, `foldL` now – I renamed `fold` to `foldR` and placed it here so we can see them side by side.

```
const foldL = (f, base, list) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    ? base
    : foldL ( f
            , f (base, first (list))
            , rest (list)
            )

const foldR = (f, base, list) =>
  isEmpty (list)
    ? base
    : f ( foldR ( f
               , base
               , rest (list)
               )
        , first (list)
        )
```

Many JavaScript developer don't know [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) exists on the `Array.prototype`. If you've only ever used commutative functions with `reduce`, you wouldn't be able to detect the difference.

Ok, so to fix our `map` and `filter`, we just have to replace our `fold` binding with `foldL`

```
const map = (f, list) =>
  foldL (mapReduce (f, concat), [], list)

const filter = (f, list) =>
  foldL (mapReduce (x => f (x) ? [ x ] : [], concat), [], list)

const square = x =>
  x * x

const gt = x => y =>
  y > x

map (square, filter (gt (2), [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
// => [ 9, 16 ]
```

With our own `map`, we *could* rewrite `depth` a little closer to our original form...

```
const depth = ({ children = [] }) =>
  isEmpty (children)
    ? 0
    : 1 + foldL ( max
                , 0
                , map (depth, children)
                )
```

But I want us to stop there and think about why that's actually worse than `depth` that uses `mapReduce` directly...

**Enough is enough**

Let's just take a moment and think about what we did there with the `map`-`filter` example. `filter` steps through our entire input array, calling `gt (2)` for each number, producing an intermediate result of `[ 3, 4 ]`. *Then* `map` calls  `square`for number in the intermediate result, producing a final value of `[ 9, 16 ]`. Data gets big and we **don't** want to see code like this:

```
myBigData.map(f).map(g).filter(h).map(i).map(j).reduce(k, base)
```

`mapReduce` is has the kind of power that will corrupt its beholder.  You think I write this answerette willingly, but I'm just a prisoner of `mapReduce`! This structure is at the heart of something some communities call *transducers* – which happens to be [a subject I've written about here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducers). We develop a *fold of folds* intuition – and like magic, exhausting multiple loops are collapsed into a single fold. If you're interested in the subject, I encourage you to read further!

Answer (score 8):

You could map the depth of every children and take the maximum value of it.

```js
function getDepth(object) {
    return 1 + Math.max(0, ...(object.children || []).map(getDepth));
}

var test = { name: 'item 1', children: [{ name: 'level 1 item', children: [{ name: 'level 2 item' }, { name: 'second level 2 item', children: [{ name: 'level 3 item' }] }] }] },
    depth = getDepth(test) - 1; // zero based

console.log(depth);
```

Comment: Did you hardcode `children` in the computing function ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret, yes, children is the main array for nested objects, as it look like.

Comment: Ok, maybe was I seeing a generic problem when OP wanted it to be more specific

Comment: You inspire me: `const depth = ({ children = [] }) => 1 + Math.max (0, ...children.map(depth))` 

Comment: @naomik, it goes even shorter without ternary: `children.length && 1 + Math.max (...children.map (depth))`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a proposal:

```
function depth(o){
  var values;
  if (Array.isArray(o)) values = o;
  else if (typeof o === "object") values = Object.keys(o).map(k=>o[k]);
  return values ? Math.max.apply(0, values.map(depth))+1 : 1;
}
```

```js
var test = {
  name: 'item 1',
  children: [{
    name: 'level 1 item',
    children: [{
      name: 'level 2 item'
    },
    {
      name: 'second level 2 item',
      children: [{
        name: 'level 3 item'
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

function depth(o){
  var values;
  if (Array.isArray(o)) values = o;
  else if (typeof o === "object") values = Object.keys(o).map(k=>o[k]);
  return values ? Math.max.apply(0, values.map(v=>depth(v)))+1 : 1;
}

console.log(depth(test))
```

EDIT: this is a generic solution. I'm still unsure whether you wanted a very specific one (i.e. with a `children` field or a generic one).

Comment: very nice answer. a very minor suggestion: `values.map(v=>depth(v))` to `values.map(depth)`

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING..!**

Just for fun..!

Here is a solution utilizing the Y combinator phenomenon. We will uritilize an ***anonymous function recursively*** to solve the problem.

The anonymous function is as follows;

```
d => (o, n = 0)  => o.children ? o.children.reduce(function(r,e){
                                                     var z = d(e,n+1);
                                                     return n > z ? n : z;
                                                   }, n)
                               : n;
```

There is a magical (and also non existent) function `d` which finds the depth of an object. If we feed our anonymous function with `d` it will return us a function with which we can feed an object and find it's depth.

So lets do it; :))

```js
var Y  = f => (g => g(g))(g => (o,z) => f(g(g))(o,z)),
    fd = Y(d => (o, n = 0)  => o.children ? o.children.reduce(function(r,e){
                                                                var z = d(e,n+1);
                                                                return n > z ? n : z;
                                                              }, n)
                                          : n),
    o  = { name: 'item 1', children: [{ name: 'level 1 item', children: [{ name: 'level 2 item' }, { name: 'second level 2 item', children: [{ name: 'level 3 item' }] }] }] },
    r  = fd(o);
console.log(r);
```

If you want to find more about the **Y combinator** you may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412648/4543207).

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
function getMaxDepth(root) {
    var currentMaxDepth = 0;

    return getDepth(currentMaxDepth, root);
}
```

You call getDepth with root, but root is never changed. So it is always the same. You should call for instance,

```
return getDepth(currentMaxDepth, root.children[0]);
```